# I'll write this easy riddle down

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
I'll write this down so you won't have,
Unless you read aloud,
I am something greater than,
A single in a crowd,

I can be small or large,
So too can be what makes up me,
Careful or I'll charge,
Away from me you'll want to be.

I can be domestic,
Or I can be bloody wild,
I'm far from antisocial,
Except for when I'm riled.
```

**What am I?**

Someone already got real close but this has sat here for a while so here's a Hint:

> It's not a swarm, or a flock of birds, have none of you _____ __ _____?

Hint #2:

> I'll write this down so you won't have [me],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

I think the answer is

> Herd/Heard

I'll write this down so you won't have,

> If it's written down, you won't have heard it.

Unless you read aloud,

> If you read it aloud, then you've heard it.

I am something greater than,
A single in a crowd,

> A herd is a large group of animals so more than a single.

I can be small or large,

> Herds of animals can come in various sizes

So too can be what makes up me,

> A herd can be mad up of non-specific animals from small to large such as pigs, sheep, cows or elephants.

Careful or I'll charge,
Away from me you'll want to be.

> You'll want to avoid a stampede.

I can be domestic,

> Herds of animals are usually found domesticated on farms.

Or I can be bloody wild,

> You can find herds of wild horses.

I'm far from antisocial,

> A herd can be used to refer to a social group of people.

Except for when I'm riled.

> You don't want to get a herd riled.

Hint 1

> "have none of you **heard of herds**"

Comment: Well I can't say it's totally wrong, but I can't accept it as is.  I was looking for the group name as the answer.

Comment: I think I understand. Is the animal sort of irrelevant then?

Comment: None-specific.  Yeah.  You could edit or just submit a new answer.  I don't mind.

Comment: Okay, I've edited

Comment: Spot on.  Accepted.  Although the hint is still wrong... both spellings of the answer should be used.  (the second one would be plural... I even intended it to rhyme haha)

Comment: Yeah, that makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Are you...

> a word?

I'll write this down so you won't have,
Unless you read aloud,

> words can be read and written!

I am something greater than,
A single in a crowd,

> a word is greater than the some of its parts (letters)

I can be small or large,
So too can be what makes up me,

> a word can be big or small, and made up of capital and lowercase letters

Careful or I'll charge,
Away from me you'll want to be.

> words can hurt!

I can be domestic,
Or I can be bloody wild,

> domestic and bloody wild are words ;)

I'm far from antisocial,
Except for when I'm riled.

> words are by their very nature social, since they are a means to communicate with others, but they can also be used to push others away

Comment: I'm not  a word.  Some good fits though.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like

> voice

I'll write this down so you won't have,
Unless you read aloud,

> You don't "have" the voice until you speak.

I can be small or large,
So too can be what makes up me

> A "small" child has a "higher" voice (and smaller?) than a "larger" grown-up.

Careful or I'll charge,
Away from me you'll want to be.

> You can remember the voice of an unpleasant person, so you'd prefer to avoid them.

I can be domestic,
Or I can be bloody wild

> The voice can be very familiar, or absolutely unknown to you, and even frightening.

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for but it is really cool!  Almost as good of a fit as mine actually.  Well explained too. +1

Comment: @Brent Haha, I was almost sure I guessed it, such a coincidence :D

Answer (score 2):

Lemme try the first thing that popped into my head.

> Is it a swarm of bees?

I am something greater than,
A single in a crowd

> there are several bees in a swarm.

I can be small or large,
So too can be what makes up me,

> Bees can be over 1.5 inches long, or under 0.08 inches long. Each wing, body adjusts size for the size of the bee.

Careful or I'll charge,
Away from me you'll want to be.

> Bees will attack you if you go near their hive.

I can be domestic,
Or I can be bloody wild,

> Many people have domesticated bees, while there are also many wild ones.

I'm far from antisocial,
Except for when I'm riled.

> bees are very social, while this. "In the event that two virgin honey bee >! queens emerge simultaneously, they fight each other to the death. After rereading the riddle, though, could it be a pig or cow?

Comment: It is not but that is the closest answer yet.  Care to explain?

Comment: You're even closer (though not quite there) with your last question.  Maybe think about it and post as another answer?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> A Dog

It can be big or small

> There are different breads of dogs

Careful or I'll charge

> A dog can attack if it is angry

Away from me you'll want to be

> You will be afraid if a dog is running at you

I can be domestic

> People keep dogs as pets

Or I can be bloody wild

> Dogs can be vicious

I am far from antisocial

> People love dogs

Except from when I'm riled

> Except when the dog is angry ar annoyed.

Comment: Sorry.  That's not what I am.  Some good fits though.